# Angular error : Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/login: 404 Not Found

Tags: angular, go, mux

I want to get login information that user enters at backend. 
Here is the backend code :-

```
package main

import (

    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

type LoginDetails struct {
   Username string `json:"username"` 
   Password string `json:"password"`
}

func login(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    var loginData LoginDetails
    err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&loginData)
    if err!=nil{
        panic(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Starting server at http://localhost:3000...")
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/dist/static")))
    router.HandleFunc("/login", login)

    headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"Authorization"})
    methodsOk := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"})
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", handlers.CORS( headersOk, methodsOk)(router)))
}
```

Angular code :-

**login.component.ts** file :-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';
import { LoginDetails } from './login';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  providers : [LoginService, LoginDetails]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm : FormGroup; 
  constructor(private loginData : LoginDetails,  private loginservice:  LoginService, private _formBuilder : FormBuilder){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      username : ['username'], 
      password : ['password']
    })
  }

  OnSubmit(){
      this.loginData.username = this.loginForm.controls.username.value;
      this.loginData.password = this.loginForm.controls.password.value;

      this.loginservice.loginUser(this.loginData).subscribe(response => {
          console.log(response)
      },(err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(err);
      });
  }

}
```

**login.service.ts** file :-

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common /http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { LoginDetails } from './login'


@Injectable()

export class LoginService{

    private _url : string = "http://localhost:3000/login";
    constructor( private http : HttpClient){}

    loginUser(loginData : LoginDetails): Observable <any>{
        console.log(loginData)
        return this.http.post(this._url, loginData, {responseType : 'text'});   
    }
}
```

Error I receive is this :- `POST http://localhost:3000/login 404 (Not Found)`.

Comment: How is your development environment set up?  Are you using any special containerization tools or virtual machines?

Comment: Also, I don't see you writing to the ResponseWriter anywhere...  There should be a line in your login function that looks something like `fmt.Fprintf(w, "I am not a 404")`

Comment: @MichaelMiller Sorry for late response. Writing to ResponseWritter does nothing.  I get same error. But I think `login` function may not be even called. And I am not using any virtual machine.

Comment: Did you try a simple curl request to your http://localhost:3000/login route if it's working fine?

Comment: @emkay I get page not found error upon that.

Comment: If from curl request you are getting the same error, then isn't the same expected by http request made by Angular?

Comment: @emkay Yes it is but I don't understand why such error is encountered.

Comment: I don't understand go, so can't help there. You may have to debug at the back-end only.

Answer (score 0):

I focused on the server part since the problem is server-side.

## Solution

I replaced `main.go` by

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)


type LoginDetails struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

func login(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    var loginData LoginDetails
    err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&loginData)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err = w.Write([]byte("ok\n"))
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Starting server at http://localhost:3000...")
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/login", login) // Registering /login before / seems to do the trick
    router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/dist/static")))

    headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"Authorization"})
    methodsOk := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"})
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", handlers.CORS(headersOk, methodsOk)(router)))
}
```

## Solution test

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username": "user", "password": "p4ssw0rd"}' http://127.0.0.1:3000/login
ok
```

## Explanation

According to [mux documentation](https://github.com/gorilla/mux):

> Routes are tested in the order they were added to the router. If two
> routes match, the first one wins:

Here is the provided example that matches your case:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/specific", specificHandler)
r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(catchAllHandler)
```

It seems like your "/" handler caught the request before your "/login" handler.